# How to report apparently missing reputation points?

Tags: support, reputation

Recently my answer to this question was accepted:

[Another Permutation Word Conundrum... With Linq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4472036/another-permutation-word-conundrum-with-linq)

However, I did not receive the expected 15 pts.

Here is a direct link to my answer.

[Another Permutation Word Conundrum... With Linq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4472036/another-permutation-word-conundrum-with-linq/4473040#4473040)

I have audited my rep and don't see the acceptance for the question/answer.

Is there a better way to report stuff like this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You edited the post a significant amount of times such that the system converted the answer to a Community Wiki post.  If you look at the revisions / edit history, you can see `[made Community Wiki]` in a recent revisions.

Due to this, you will not earn more rep from this post.

[What are Community Wiki posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts)

Comment: Indeed, see also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts

Comment: Thanks. I had no idea there was a "penalty" for revising/expanding an answer. I guess I'll be more careful next time!

Comment: @wageoghe, there isn't for just a couple of edits.